# Curl Not working as intended inside a function

Tags: php, html, curl

Lately i was trying out php_curl and when i just had the curl script it worked just fine ! but when i added it inside a function and call it on a button click .. I got the "wikipedia" page directly and not the button :/

why is that ? is it something like curl scripts gets executed first always ?

and i can't seem to load facebook using curl

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

     <?php
          function hello() {

             $ch=curl_init();
             $url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast";
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
             $response = curl_exec($ch);
             echo $response ;

                           }
    ?>

<input type="button" name="Release" onclick="document.write('<?php hello() ?>');" value="Click to Release">

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, which of the both Options your trying.

**Preload and Show on Buttonclick**

You need to activate Return Transfer

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

But be aware: You need to escape the Write sequence

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

**Execute on Button Click**

You can not direct execute a Method on Server Side from Clientside. :D

This is not a `CURL` problem. What you have to do:

On Button Click call via `AJAX` to `Wikipedia`

or

Create a Formular, and on submit you call `CURL`

Can't give a more acurate answer. Please google `Client Side`, `Server Side`, `Formular PHP` and `AJAX` if you have further Questions. This are basics.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you directly echoed the source code of wikipedia page.
Since page of wikipedia has `"` it closed onclick event handler.

This is neither problem of js/php it is logical mistake.
If you check source code of your generated page you will see code beginning with

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<input type="button" name="Release" onclick="document.write('
...
```

Which confirms the issue.
I you want to replace data of page.You can write data in a div,hide it by default and when user clicks unhide data. Using div is peaceful than writing a blog of data in eventhandler.